# Array compare string

Tags: java, arrays, compare

Hi im trying to figure out why my code isn't doing what i want it to do. when i run the code it always does the if statement in the for loop. i changed the logic around but it always does the for loop all the time. im not sure why . thanks for the help

```
            for (int col =0; col< s ; col++){
        System.out.print(col+ ": ");
        for (int row = 0; row<s; row++)
        {
            x=val[row][col];
            if (table[row][col]==row)
            {
                System.out.print(x+1);
            }
            //System.out.print(val[col][row]+" ");
            if (row+1==s)
                System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: remove the ; after the if statement

Comment: Abi's  right. My question is, because of the tittle, are you comparing Strings in that piece of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a semicolon at the end of the if statement, remove it.

```
 if (x==2);
```

Comment: is there any reason why the loop stops during the 2nd iteration ?

Comment: What is the max value for s?, your condition is probably satisfied within the second iteration

Comment: i pasted the code on top. i want it to go through every value and count the value but i keep on stoping randomly

Comment: 2 things - what is val[row][col] and table [row][col]?and second thing please don't modify the original question after it has been answered.it will be better if you post a new question

Comment: they stand for rows and columns. i'll post a new question then